# Double to string conversions for calculator

Tags: c++, c++17, double, precision

I am currently developing a cCalc, which is a graphical user interface calculator that looks like the built-in calculator in Windows 10 in engineering mode. My project is based on C++17, using FLTK as a GUI wrapper, and `long double` as the main type for working with numbers. I am using MinGW 10.2.

Today, I discovered a problem with converting from `long double` type to `std::string`, since I don't know how to choose the number of decimal places. The C++ language has built-in capabilities for converting from `long double` to `std::string`, but they are not suitable because:

1. `std::to_string(long double)` always uses six digits of decimal places. If the user wants to count `40 + 1`, he expects `41` but `41.000000` will not be quite expected.
2. `std::ostringstream s` with `s.precision(n)` is also a bad idea. Any option with a `fixed` precision will not work, as the real part with important digits may be discarded.
3. `std::ostringstream s` without `s.precision(n)` is not suitable, since the automatic selection of the number of decimal places is not always correct. For example:

   ```cpp
   std::ostringstream s;
   s << 3.14159265L;
   std::cout << s.str();
   ```

   This will give `3.14159`, 3 digits with valuable information have been lost.

I was programming in C# a few years ago, and as far as I remember, the easy way of `System.Convert.ToString(double d)` worked very well.

**Question:**
What is a good and free-licensed implementation that solves the described problem? I am expecting an implementation that for large (or small) numbers uses scientific notation.

Also, I do not want to add huge libraries, like Boost, to my project.

Comment: The good old C `sprintf` (using the `%Lg` format specifier) may help you. At least, that will decide *internally* whether or not to use scientific notation for a given field width/precision.

Comment: uhm, create a your own object with `long unsigned int exp; bool positive, long long unsigned int number` and if you have like `41.00001` you save in the sign `true`, in the number `4100001` and in the exp `5`... than you can override `operator string() const &` and the other way, and you have "your own method of saving it"

Comment: There's also the [fmt library](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html). If you can go from C++17 to C++20 you don't even have to use an external dependency because there's very similar functionality in [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format).

Comment: Libfmt is the way to go. Or `std::to_chars`, if your compiler is recent enough.